# Are Franky & Bon Clay voiced by the same voice actor?

Tags: one-piece

I'm just wondering if the voice actor of Franky is the same as the one of Mr. 2 Bon Clay. They sound the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Japanese, both Franky and Mr. 2 Bon Clay are voiced by [Kazuki Yao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuki_Yao).[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_characters#Franky)[<sup>[2]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_characters#Bon_Clay)

In both the 4kids English dub and Funimation English dub, they are voiced by different people.

Comment: Thanks. :) I thought it was the same person but i wasn't sure. I also don't wanted to google it because spoiler alert! ;)

Comment: @NathanTshiananga http://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/ is a great place to look this up without any spoilers.

Comment: @Thebluefish Thanks for the site. I'm definitely bookmarking.

Comment: @NathanTshiananga There's also generally not spoilers on IMDb... and they have all of the actors and the roles they play. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0388629/